# Camel - Can't access rest service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm running camel via spring and camel boot with embedded tomcat.
I have a simple camel route that is configuring correctly and consuming that I can see in the logs,  but when i try  to access it, it is giving 404 with `localhost:8080/hi`.

**My Route**

```
 @Component
 public class ServiceRoute extends RouteBuilder {

 @Autowired
 private SampleBean sampleBean;

 @Override
 public void configure() throws Exception {
   from("rest:get:hi").to("bean:sampleBean");
 }
}
```

**My Main class**

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "routes", "service" },
    excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class,     
    type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)})

public class Application  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

**Gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:2.17.0'

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-
web', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'

compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-servlet', version:  
'2.18.1'
}
```

**Logs**

```
2016-12-12 12:37:39.860  INFO 24684 --- [           main] root.Application                         : Starting Application on ram.tscpt.local with PID 24684 (/Users/srikanth/emulya/build/classes/main started by srikanth in /Users/srikanth/emulya)
2016-12-12 12:37:39.865  INFO 24684 --- [           main] root.Application                         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-12-12 12:37:39.979  INFO 24684 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4facf68f: startup date [Mon Dec 12 12:37:39 SAST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-12 12:37:41.866  INFO 24684 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a11fb1e5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-12-12 12:37:42.597  INFO 24684 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-12-12 12:37:42.617  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-12-12 12:37:42.618  INFO 24684 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2016-12-12 12:37:42.756  INFO 24684 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-12-12 12:37:42.756  INFO 24684 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2782 ms
2016-12-12 12:37:42.959  INFO 24684 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-12-12 12:37:42.983  INFO 24684 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-12 12:37:42.984  INFO 24684 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-12 12:37:42.985  INFO 24684 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-12 12:37:42.985  INFO 24684 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-12 12:37:43.525  INFO 24684 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4facf68f: startup date [Mon Dec 12 12:37:39 SAST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-12 12:37:43.651  INFO 24684 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-12-12 12:37:43.653  INFO 24684 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-12-12 12:37:43.703  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-12 12:37:43.707  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-12 12:37:43.778  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-12 12:37:44.557  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.converter.DefaultTypeConverter   : Loaded 196 type converters
2016-12-12 12:37:44.890  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-12-12 12:37:44.970  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
2016-12-12 12:37:44.973  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
2016-12-12 12:37:44.974  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2016-12-12 12:37:44.976  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.c.m.ManagedManagementStrategy        : JMX is enabled
2016-12-12 12:37:45.548  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry   : Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
2016-12-12 12:37:45.871  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2016-12-12 12:37:46.023  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: servlet:/hi?httpMethodRestrict=GET
2016-12-12 12:37:46.024  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started.
2016-12-12 12:37:46.026  INFO 24684 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.050 seconds
2016-12-12 12:37:46.147  INFO 24684 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-12-12 12:37:46.157  INFO 24684 --- [           main] root.Application                         : Started Application in 6.985 seconds (JVM running for 7.475)
```

Comment: Could you please add logs to your route before and after your bean ? Also, what is `sampleBean`supposed to do ?

Comment: Yes I have added logs and I don't see any issue with configuring and consuming route but for some reason I can't hit that service, it is 404 and the `sampleBean` just logs one line @MickaëlB

Comment: If you can actually see the route being consumed with the logs, my guess is that your bean is not correctly autowired. Can you provided more information about `sampleBean` (java code and spring configuration) ?

Comment: could you post the error that spring throws before you get the 404(open logs in debug). It looks like , it is trying to resolve it from the default dispatcher which is listening to  `/*`. Have you defined a `ViewResolver` too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not working, because the Camel HTTP Servlet is not registered. `CamelAutoConfiguration` just starts the camel context.

You need to register the servlet yourself. The default name of the camel servlet is `CamelServlet`. Change your `Application` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "routes", "service" },
    excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class,     
    type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)})

public class Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "/service/*");
        registration.setName("CamelServlet");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

And then try to access `http://localhost/service/hi`

Btw, you don't need to add `@Configuration` to the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: it worked. Thanks so much @Strelok, Really this world need techies like you :)

Comment: This is written nowhere I could find. Even the `camel-example-spring-boot-rest-jpa` example is failing when I run it and try to reach the /books endpoint.